# .change() causes element content to be deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have started creating a simple monthly payment estimator and I have found a weird bug that only happens when I change the term select option. If you use the slider, the monthly payment updates and also adds the comma in the number via the `.digits()` method. But, when you change `#loan__term`, it clears the number altogether. There must be a conflict with `.change()` and `.digits()` because if I remove it, the `.change()` method works as expected. Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.digits = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).text(
        $(this)
          .text()
          .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
      );
    });
  };

  function updateMonthlyPayment() {
    $loanAmount = $("#loan__amount span").html();
    $loanTerm = $("#loan__term option:selected").val();
    if ($loanTerm == "for 24 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.045878 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 36 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.032 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 48 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.025085 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 60 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.020963 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    }
  }

  $("#loan__amount__slider").slider({
    max: 125000,
    min: 5000, 
    step: 1000,
    value: 50000,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#loan__amount__num")
        .position({
          my: "center bottom",
          at: "center top",
          of: ui.handle,
          offset: "0, 10"
        });
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#loan__amount span").html(ui.value);
      $("#loan__amount__num span").html(ui.value);
      updateMonthlyPayment();
      $("#loan__amount span").digits();
      $("#loan__amount__num span").digits();

      var delay = function() {
        var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data("index.uiSliderHandle");
        $("#loan__amount__num")
          .position(
            {
              my: "center bottom",
              at: "center top",
              of: ui.handle,
              offset: "0, 10"
            }
          );
      };

      // wait for the ui.handle to set its position
      setTimeout(delay, 5);
    }
  });

  $("#loan__term").change(updateMonthlyPayment);
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jrayhartley/pen/BVjdbM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
$loanAmount = parseFloat($("#loan__amount span").html().replace(',',''));
```

Your $().html() returns "50,000" which then when you go to do math on it, you get `NaN`, and when you set $().html(NaN) you get a blank. To get around this you can remove the "," by using the replace function and then parsing the value.

To debug this (hopefully will help you learning to debug:) I simply used console.log() statements before the html() which should write **something** to the cell (found NaN instead!), and worked the way back to your math... then back to the "50,000" causing an error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only did you fix my issue, but you also learn'd me something. Thanks, Cody!

Comment: This is a bad idea. Really bad. Putting a formatted value into the DOM and reading it back like this to do calculations is a prime example of how not to program.

Comment: No problem! As Chris has said this isn't the "best" way, but I assume you'll learn about designing your programs as you progress further to create clean programs and when it is necessary to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

with slider -> first calculate the rate and then do the digits
with select -> calculate based on the digits

so its 40000 with slider and "40,000" with the select

quick and dirty fix
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrLwPM?editors=1111

```
  function updateMonthlyPayment() {
   $loanAmount = $("#loan__amount span").html().replace(",","");
     $loanTerm = $("#loan__term option:selected").val();
    if ($loanTerm == "for 24 months") {
        $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.045878 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 36 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.032 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 48 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.025085 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    } else if ($loanTerm == "for 60 months") {
      $("#monthly__payment span")
        .html(Math.floor($loanAmount * 0.020963 / 100 * 100))
        .digits();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

- You change the selected item in the list,
- `$("#loan__term").change(…)` calls `updateMonthlyPayment()`,
- `$loanAmount = $("#loan__amount span").html();` <-- Problem

The `html` of the `#loan__amount span` has already been altered using `.digits()`. So the calculation cannot be done.

That's why when you comment the `… .digits()` lines, it works.

Here is a working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxyXOq where:

- I used a `data` attribute to store the value not formatted,
- I tried to simplify other things

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The most problematic issue is that you aren't separating your data from your presentation. Putting formatted values in spans, then reading the values back from the spans (instead of using variables) is a very bad idea and error prone.

So is comparing strings when you could be using values instead in your `<select>`. You should grab the value directly from the slider, and the value directly from the select.

I overhauled the code:

```js
const interest = {
  "24": 0.045878,
  "36": 0.032,
  "48": 0.025085,
  "60": 0.020963
};

const loan = {
  min: 5000,
  max: 125000,
  step: 1000
};

var initialAmount = 50000;

$.fn.dollars = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var n = Number(this.innerHTML || this.value).toLocaleString("en-US");
    $(this).text("$" + n);
  });
};

function updateMonthlyPayment() {
  var loanAmount = $("#loan__amount__slider").slider("option", "value");
  var loanTerm = $("#loan__term").val();
  $("#monthly__payment")
    .html(Math.floor(loanAmount * interest[loanTerm]))
    .dollars();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loan__amount, #loan__amount__num")
    .text(initialAmount)
    .dollars();
  $("#loan__min")
    .text(loan.min)
    .dollars();
  $("#loan__max")
    .text(loan.max)
    .dollars();

  $("#loan__term").change(updateMonthlyPayment);

  $("#loan__amount__slider").slider({
    max: loan.max,
    min: loan.min,
    step: loan.step,
    value: initialAmount,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#loan__amount").text(ui.value).dollars();
      $("#loan__amount__num").text(ui.value).dollars();
      updateMonthlyPayment();

      var delay = function() {
        var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data("index.uiSliderHandle");
        $("#loan__amount__num").position({
          my: "center bottom",
          at: "center top",
          of: ui.handle,
          offset: "0, 10"
        });
      };

      // wait for the ui.handle to set its position
      setTimeout(delay, 5);
    }
  });
  updateMonthlyPayment();
});
```

```css
#loan__amount__num {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#loan__min {
  float: left;
}

#loan__max {
  float: right;
}

#slider-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

<h3>Financing Amount</h3>
<div id="slider-box">
  <div id="loan__amount__num" style="left: calc(37.5% - 25px);"></div>
  <div id="loan__amount__slider"></div>
  <div id="loan__min"></div>
  <div id="loan__max"></div>
</div>
<p>Amount: <span id="loan__amount"></span></p>

<h3>Estimated Monthly Payment</h3>
<div id="monthly__payment"></div>

<select id="loan__term">
  <option value="24">for 24 months</option>
  <option value="36" selected="selected">for 36 months</option>
  <option value="48">for 48 months</option>
  <option value="60">for 60 months</option>
</select>
```